# Assigning a controller from a directive angularjs 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm switching from angularJS 1.0 to 1.2 and I'm having some trouble assigning a controller to a directive with a clean scope, without defining a controller in my html with ng-controller.

consider the following scenario:

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('parentCtrl',function($scope,$element,$attrs) {
  $scope.helloworld = function(){                                                   
    console.log('hello world from ParentCtrl controller')
  }
})

.controller('childCtrl',function($scope,$element,$attrs) {
    $scope.helloworld = function(){ 

       console.log('hello world from ChildCtrl controller')

    }
})
.directive('ngParent', function() {
  return {
    controller:'ParentCtrl'
  }
})
.directive('ngChild', function() {
  return {
      controller:'ChildCtrl',
      scope:{},
      link:function(scope,element,attrs){

      }
   }
})
```

And HTML:

```
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-parent>
      <button ng-click="helloworld()">Parent Scope click </button>
      <div ng-child>
         <button ng-click="helloworld()">Child Scope click </button>
      </div>  
  </body>
```

Right now, both buttons will log "hello world from ParentCtrl controller". However, if I change the parameter scope:{} to scope:true in the ngChild directive, it works and the buttons are calling their respective scopes' helloworld function. But that doesn't make a clean scope like I want it to.

How do I make a clean scope in a directive with angular 1.2, without assigning the controller in my view?

Thanks,
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

because you're not creating a new scope both directives are using the same scope and the definition of "helloworld" function gets overwritten. so either you need to change the name of the function or create a new scope,

and by the way i think you're using directives wrong.
instead of defining directives and assign controllers to them you should use ng-controller and for each of controllers set the helloworld function in their own scopes. and write a directive (if it's really needed) to get that function and call it when you need to.

Comment: You could add controllers to your directives.  I found it useful when organizing most of the non-UI code assigned to controller while my DOM-manipulating code is in the link() callback.  In this scenario my business logic cannot exist without the rest of the directive's UI.  It makes for much cleaner code IMHO.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to combine ui and business logic, but since i don't know your exact scenario,it might be valid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realize that the helloworld gets overwritten because a new scope is not created... That's why I used the code as an example. I don't agree that you should use ng-controller in your view instead of assigning it in the directive. In a MVC framework you should be able to make a html template with a controller and a model that is separated from the HTML. E.g. making a <ng-my-element></ng-my-element> should be possible, with the option of changing controller and options from the directive instead of changing every html instance of it...